# Rename files into numbers, starting with a specific number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I want to rename all files in a directory to be sequential numbers:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

and so on...

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.txt"; done
```

The code does work, but I need to start with a specific number.  For example, I may want to start with the number `49` instead of the number `1`.

Is there any way to do this in terminal (on a Mac)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use something like [`nl` with the `-v` option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html) to set a starting line number other than 1, but instead, you can just use Bash features:

```
i=1
for f in *; do
    [[ -f $f ]] && mv "$f" $((i++)).txt
done
```

where `i` is set to the initial value you want.

This also avoids parsing the output of `ls`, which is [recommended to avoid](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, I use a glob (`*`) and a test (`-f`) to make sure that I'm actually manipulating files and not directories.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Will accept answer in 4 mins when it lets me.  Thanks!